# Openedge JDBC: Failure getting table lock on table PUB._File

Tags: java, jdbc, openedge, progress-db

In my application I am trying to add a column to the table, I will be using the column as unique identifier to update the other columns of the table.

In order to do that, i am locking the table in exclusive mode and then adding the new column UNIQ_ID. I am getting the below error while trying to alter the table.

**Update Query : LOCK TABLE PUB."customer" IN EXCLUSIVE MODE**

**Update Query : ALTER TABLE PUB."customer" ADD (UNIQ_ID integer)**

**java.sql.SQLException: [DataDirect][OpenEdge JDBC Driver][OpenEdge] Failure getting table lock on table PUB._File.**

what am I missing here?

Comment: Some other transaction is holding a lock on _File table. You need to either commit or rollback that transaction

Comment: Do not do that directly. You probably won´t be able to add all related fields and dependances correctly, so just use Progress tools for that. You can read the data from there all you want, but writing to meta schema in Progress is a very bad idea. See Tom´s answer below, Tom Bascom is a key person in the Progress world.

Answer (score 2):

Directly manipulating the meta schema is a very bad idea and probably won't work.

You should use the tools that Progress provides to add tables, columns, indexes etc.